# Include quotation marks around a variable in a string

Tags: java, sql, database

I want to compile a query called FinalQuery, but a part of it has to be inside quote marks. And the part that has to go inside the quote marks is a string variable.

To go into more detail -

1. This FinalQuery query is given to JFreeChart to make a pie chart.
2. But FinalQuery is compiled within the program, as per a certain choices of the user.
3. Those choice by the user are made in a JComboBox.

Here is the code -

```
public class Execute extends JFrame {
private JComboBox comboAccountName = new JComboBox();

public Execute() {
    ....................

    getContentPane().add(comboAccountName);
    comboAccountName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            CompileQuery();
        }
    });

final String query = CompileQuery(); //variable query is executed in JFreeChart

JButton btnDraw = new JButton("Draw");
    btnDraw.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Symbol", Font.BOLD, 15));
    btnDraw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
JDBCPieDataset hdataset = new JDBCPieDataset(DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB(), query);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Query",
                        hdataset, true, true, false);
...............}


String CompileQuery()
{
    String getAccountName = (String)comboAccountName.getSelectedItem();
    String FinalQuery = "SELECT status, COUNT(status) FROM main WHERE [Account Name] = "+getAccountName+" GROUP BY status";
    System.out.println(FinalQuery);
    return FinalQuery;
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Execute frame1 = new Execute();
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

But in a SQL query the WHERE [XYZ] = ? has to be provided in quotes. Eg. WHERE [Account Name] = "John".

Currently my query is a format -

SELECT xyz FROM pqr WHERE abc = variable name

i.e.

```
SELECT status, count(status) 
FROM main
WHERE [Account Name] = getaccountName (variable)
GROUP BY status;
```

I want to put variable name in quote marks so that it looks like

SELECT xyz FROM pqr WHERE abc = "variable name"

```
SELECT status, count(status) 
FROM main
WHERE [Account Name] = "getaccountName" (variable)
GROUP BY status;
```

Please suggest how I can make my FinalQuery string variable have quotes around another variable inside it.

Comment: I think `... WHERE [Account Name] = \""+getAccountName + "\"...";` should work.

Comment: Just escaping the quotes should work, if you can't use a PreparedStatement. Also, method and variable names should start with a lowercase letter in Java.

Answer (score 2):

> but a part of it has to be inside quote marks. And the part that has to go inside the quote marks is a string variable

Use a PreparedStatment. It will build the SQL for you using the proper syntax and you can easily specify constants or variables to be used:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Page (Name, Title) VALUES (?, ?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, nameVariable );
stmt.setString( 2, "Title1" );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I can't use PreparedStatement. My JFreeChart is setup like this (updated question)